# How to convert Telerik report template (.trdx) to DevExpress report template (.repx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, devexpress, reporting

I have Telerik report template (.trdx) in xml format, and intent to convert into DevExpress report template (.repx) in xml format too. Both are significantly different.

1) Is there any tool to help for conversion?
2) Alternatively to use transient file, since DevExpress report able to import Crystal report, ActiveReport. 
But is there any tool to convert Telerik report to Crystal report/Active report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Que 1: Is there any tool to help for conversion?**

> No, DevExpress does not have any tool for conversion.

**Que 2: Alternatively to use transient file, since DevExpress report able to import Crystal report, ActiveReport.**

> Again No, You to transit manually.

I have not found any way or tool that do desired operation as you want. Even DevExpress guys do not provide any kind of special tool that allows converting Telerik reports related items to XtraReports.

I think you got answer from DevExpress support also..
[Converting Telerik Report to DevExpress Report](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T398596)

You have to take help from DevExpress guys and keep doing transition from Telerik control to DevExpress. It may be the right path to choose.